# Compound Interest Formula With Monthly Investment Increase

Tags: financial-literacy, compound-interest, automation

I'm looking to solve this problem:

If I were to start investing now, With a 4% annual return compounded monthly what is the function for my return if my monthly input is initially $2000 then for every month here after 2% is added. For example:

month 1 deposit = 2000

month 2 deposit = 2040

month 3 deposit = 2080.80
etc.

I understand the compound interest formula with a uniform monthly deposit to be:

```
p*(i+1)^t + d * ((1+i)^t - 1)/(i) * (1+i)
```

where p is our initial value, t is the number of compounding periods and d to be the periodic deposit. But I'm struggling to find the formula with the increase in the monthly deposit.

I have a feeling that there isn't a straight forward formula (I hope to be shown wrong!) but maybe it is possible to write a python script with a loop or a rrnewing d variable?

Comment: Not sure how sustainable a 2% *monthly* increase in contributions is. By the end of year three your contribution amount has just about doubled...

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding the initial value `p` for the moment

the monthly interest rate `i = 0.04/12`

so with initial deposit `d = 2000` the value after three months is

```
d (1 + 0.02)^0 (1 + i)^3 +
d (1 + 0.02)^1 (1 + i)^2 +
d (1 + 0.02)^2 (1 + i)^1 = 6161.43
```

This can be expressed as a summation with

```
t = 3
x = 0.02
```

[image]

and the summation can be converted to a formula [by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039786/induction-of-closed-form-of-summation)

[image]

Adding the initial value compounded over three months `p (1 + i)^t`

```
future value = p (1 + i)^t + (d (1 + i) ((1 + i)^t - (1 + x)^t))/(i - x)
```

Comment: Your `i` is wrong - `0.33%`(etc) monthly gives ~ `4.0742%` annual. `i` should be `(1.04)^(1/12)`, approx `0.003274`. Your algebra looks right though.

Comment: Depending on the product, they might advertise 4% annual return and it actually be 0.33% monthly, or it might be as you say @AakashM.  Something to take into consideration one way or the other.

Comment: @AakashM If the interest rate is stated as "compounded monthly" that means it is a [nominal rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation).  In the US APR is nominal and in Europe APR is effective.  A nominal APR of 4% compounded monthly is equal to a 4.07415% effective annual interest rate.